# como saber si el expansion-panel esta abierto en Vue JS?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

soy nueva en Vue y queria saber si hay alguna manera de saber si el `expansion-panel` esta abierto o cerrado. En base a eso debo cambiar el color de unos iconos.
Muchas Gracias!

Comment: segun la documentacion si.. tuviste algun problema leyendo la misma?

Comment: Depende de la versión que estes usando. En la documentación hay [un ejemplo](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels/#external-control) que te puede servir de guia